# Make an image spin, and as it spins over a div, change it's color... maybe with a mask?

Tags: css, mask

I have a circle logo, with text on the outside, and a small circle in the middle.  I plan to make the logo spin using some CSS3.  That's relatively easily.

The tricky bit is that I want to make the logo change to BLACK when it's over a pink div, and change to WHITE as it moves over the black part...

I think this is achieved with a mask or a filter, but I just cannot work out how to do it...

I've setup a codepen with a basic example:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JQYQdp

```
<div class="main-header">
  <div class="spinning">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/pKVwqhY/test-logo.png" alt="test-logo" border="0">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pink">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-header {
  width:100%;
  background-color:black;
  height:200px;
}

.pink {
  width:100%;
  background-color:pink;
  height:200px;
}
.spinning {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2000;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  top:100px;
  right:0;
  -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
}


@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

As the text of the image spins over the PINK background, I want that part of the text to be black, whilst the top half is still white...

Answer (score 1):

`mix-blend-mode` will get you most of the way.

> The mix-blend-mode CSS property sets how an element's content should blend with the content of the element's parent and the element's background.
>
> <sup>[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)</sup>

```css
.main-header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
}

.pink {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 200px;
}

.spinning {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2000;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  right: 10px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
  <div class="spinning">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/pKVwqhY/test-logo.png" alt="test-logo" border="0">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pink">
</div>
```

Comment: Nice - thanks for the answer.  Is there a way of getting the text to be pure black when it's on the pink?  as currently it looks an off green.